# Trouble building a custom WP_query

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to override the default query on my client's `single.php` page and can't seem to affect the query at all, despite seemingly doing it correctly (guess not!).

I simply want to eliminate one category of posts from the query. Its slug is "homepage-item" and its category is 10 (when I hover over its name in the Dashboard listing of categories, I see (in part): "...taxonomy=category&tag_ID=10..."

I've simply inserted this near the top of my single.php:

```
<?php
    $customArgs = array( 
        'category__not_in' => '10' 
    );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $customArgs );
?>
```

...and I added my custom query's variable name here:

```
<?php
    if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
        $count = 0;
        while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) {
            $custom_query->the_post();
            $count++;
?>
```

But whatever I do, my query seems unaffected - the same content appears. I even tried changing `$customArgs` to remove virtually all content but see no change.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but... what might it be?

Hope someone can help!
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an action you could hook into. It's called [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and it lets you alter the query before the query is run.

This code should be placed into your functions.php file.

```
function my_exclude_category( $query ) 
{
    if ( $query->is_singular('post') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-10' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_exclude_category' );
```

**Please note.** Your approach is not working because you are trying to create a new query within a theme template file that is supposed to be used to display a singular post. Also, you aren't affecting the main query by creating a new WP_Query. That's what the `pre_get_posts` action hook is for. The template file that is used for displaying a list of posts is e.g. `archive.php` please see the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks @marcwiest. I had avoided pre_get_posts due to reading [this in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts): "pre_get_posts will not work if used in template files (e.g., archive.php), since they are called after the query has been completed." The trouble is, I built this site a long time ago and would do it differently now, but all kinds of custom content display is hard-coded into index.php and it's now simplest if a certain category doesn't appear there. I don't want it to be excluded everywhere though, which the function would do - right?

Comment: Ah, I see it would be limited to single posts, i.e. not the front page. Will try it!

Comment: It seems not to be working, but I should clarify: I'm still seeing a news item (wanted to remove these) as the Next post in the "Previous/Next" area, when I'm on the last-added of the posts I do want to see (ski resort reviews, the only kind of post I want to see here). I'd assumed that if WP_query didn't include News (cat. 10) posts, I'd see no "Next" link with a News item. Why might it still be there? (And yes, I've cleared my cache, etc.)

Comment: I'm sure that `pre_get_posts` will do the trick. Take some time to study [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) as well as it's [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags). By using the example code from my answer and the documentation you will be able to modify the query any way you need.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will dig deep into WP_Query before I ask for further help (and hopefully won't need it!).

Comment: If the information provided helped you solve it, would you mind checking it as the right answer? Thanks

Comment: I've accepted your answer as correct Marc - it certainly was helpful and has put me on the right track even if it isn't totally solved yet. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I totally appreciate being pointed in the right direction, @MarcWiest, but I must admit that, now that I'm tackling this anew, I'm running into the same issue. The code you suggested seems like it should work perfectly, but even if I do an over-broad version and just change $query _everywhere_, it does not change a thing.  I see from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992401/wordpress-pre-get-posts-not-working that var_dump might reveal useful info, but in my case every var appears to be "string(0)".  I simply don't know what to try next...

Comment: You have placed the code snippet I provided into `functions.php`, right? It's the only thing I can think of as to why the `$query` variable would be empty. Please also be sure to have this variable defined within the callback function definition.

Comment: Alternatively, search you code base for any other `pre_get_posts` modifications.

Comment: Yep, it's definitely in functions.php. It's a child theme, I don't suppose that makes a difference? Unless pre_get_posts is also called in the parent theme's functions.php perhaps... but that doesn't preclude me also using it, right? Nevertheless, I will search the codebase as you say and see what else might be interfering.